# How to store 100 digit number in C using strings

Tags: c

> My problem is that i dont know what this functions do, thats program
>   from my teacher(not whole program just functions). Just wanna ask you what this functions do, mainly why
>   i store my number from right to left at string? thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 1000



void str_to_num(char *str, char *number, int *dlzka)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < MAX; i++)
            number[i] = 0;
        *dlzka = strlen(str);
        for(i = 0; i < *dlzka; i++)
            cis[(*dlzka) - 1 - i] = str[i] - '0';

    }

    void plus(char *cislo, int *d1, char *cis2, int d2)
    {
        int i; prenos = 0;
        if(*d1 < d2)
            *d1 = d2;
        for(i = 0; i < *d1; i++)
        {
            pom = number[i] + number[i];
            pom += prenos;
            number[i] = pom % 10;
            prenos = pom / 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your teacher intentionally using non-English variable names to confuse you?

Comment: @usr2564301 yes im from slovakia, sry i can translate it to you but i just wanna know what this functions do.

Comment: The function names ought to give you a hint. Do you have reason to believe they do something entirely else?

Comment: It does nothing since it does not even compile

Comment: `d` is not declared in `main`. Should it be `pom` instead? Also, about *"why i store my number from right to left at string"*, consider how you'd sum two big numbers, with pencil and papers.

Comment: Pleas edit your question and make sure that the names of the parameters match the names of the variables used in the body of the function. That is a riddle you shouldn't ask people to solve _before_ they can help you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the lesson your teacher should be teaching:

1. There is a difference between the numerical value of 1, and the computer code (ASCII for example) that is used to represent character `1` displayed on the screen or typed on the keyboard.

Every time you see `1` on the screen, your computer sees 49 in memory.
`0` is 48, 2 is 50 and so on.

Conveniently, all digit characters are arranged in a sequence from 0 to 9, so to convert their character codes to their numeric values all you have to do is subtract the character code of zero to get the digit position in the sequence.

For example: `49 - 48 = 1 --> '1' - '0' = 1`

And this is how the first function, `str_to_num` works.

2. C language does not provide a variable large enough to work with 100 digit numbers, so you need to sum them up one digit at a time.

The second function has completely wrong variable names, but it is still pretty obvious what it is *trying* to do:
It sums up two single digit numbers, then stores the ones part of the result in an array and the tenth (if sum is > 9) in a helper variable.

As already suggested in the comments, this is how you sum up numbers manually on a page one digit at a time.

I don't know what `prenos` means in your language, but in English this variable should be called `carry` and it keeps the overflowing tens digit for the next round.

There is however something missing from the sum function: if the sum of the last (leftmost) two digits is more than 9, the extra 1 will be lost, and the result will be wrong.

Check the original code your teacher gave you - either you copied it wrong, or he is giving a bad example.